# Bash script for archive logs

Tags: bash

need a assist from bash scripting experts for create a script.

my requirement -
need find all logs in source location(location mentioned in below) which older than 3 days then move that all logs to another location and archive as below .zip file in last example. also planning to run this script every night as a cron job.

*example log source location -*
**/tmp/logs/source/2018/09/15/server1_logs**

*after archived zip file should be like this in destination -*
**/tmp/logs/destination/2018_09_15.zip**

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_SOURCE="/tmp/logs/source"                               
LOG_DESTINATION="/tmp/logs/destination"                                 
ARCHIVE_AFTER="3"

archiveDay=$(date "+%d" -d "$ARCHIVE_AFTER days ago")
archiveMonth=$(date "+%m" -d "$ARCHIVE_AFTER days ago")
archiveYear=$(date "+%Y" -d "$ARCHIVE_AFTER days ago")
logArchiveSrcDirectory=$LOG_SOURCE"/"$archiveYear"/"$archiveMonth"/"$archiveDay
logArchiveDstZipFile=$LOG_DESTINATION"/"$archiveYear"_"$archiveMonth"_"$archiveDay".zip"
echo $logArchiveSrcDirectory
echo $logArchiveDstZipFile

# Log Archive Process
zip -r  $logArchiveDstZipFile $logArchiveSrcDirectory

# Delete original log directory if archiving successfull 
if [ -f "$logArchiveDstZipFile" ] 
    then
    rm -r $logArchiveSrcDirectory
fi
```

this script working but its only move and zipped only the day which 3 days before, but rest of other old directories still there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: thanks, I have tried with above code but having an issue, so i have updated the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can connect many commands and features of bash to develop solution. Here's my version:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_SOURCE="/tmp/logs/source"                               
LOG_DESTINATION="/tmp/logs/destination"                                 
ARCHIVE_AFTER="3"

# That directory probably exists already but let us say it doesn't
mkdir -p "$LOG_DESTINATION"

find "$LOG_SOURCE" -type d -regextype gnu-awk -regex "$LOG_SOURCE/[[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}" \
    | sed -r -n 's#^.*([0-9]{4})/([0-1][0-9])/([0-3][0-9])$#\1 \2 \3#p' \
    | while read Y M D; do
        if [[ "$Y$M$D" < $(date "+%Y%m%d" -d "$ARCHIVE_AFTER days ago") ]]
        then
            logArchiveSrcDirectory="$LOG_SOURCE/$Y/$M/$D"
            logArchiveDstZipFile="$LOG_DESTINATION/"$Y"_"$M"_"$D".zip"

            echo $logArchiveSrcDirectory
            echo $logArchiveDstZipFile

            if zip -r  "$logArchiveDstZipFile" "$logArchiveSrcDirectory"
            then
                rm -r "$logArchiveSrcDirectory"
            fi

        fi
    done
```

Let's examine what I did:

- `find` will print the files that matches our criteria:

  - `"$LOG_SOURCE"`: It is the directory where the search will begin. It will search recursively from that directory
  - `-type d`: We are looking only for directories
  - `-regextype gnu-awk`: The next regular expression option will use the dialect of GNU awk
  - `-regex "$LOG_SOURCE/[[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2}"`: We are looking for path that begin with our source directory following by four, 2 and 2 digit number separated by slashes
- We will take the output from find and connect it so `sed`. We use `sed` to transform each line from `find`

  - `-r`: We will use extended regular expressions for this step
  - `-n`: We don't want to display lines that doesn't match what we are searching for
  - `'s#^.*([0-9]{4})/([0-1][0-9])/([0-3][0-9])$#\1 \2 \3#p'`: We isolate the Year, Month and Day component from each line. We separate each element with a space
- We use `while read Y M D; do` to read each line for the output of `sed` and set the variables `$Y`, `$M` and `$D` respectively

  - `if [[ "$Y$M$D" < $(date "+%Y%m%d" -d "$ARCHIVE_AFTER days ago") ]]`: We compare lexicographily the current date being processed and the output of `date` from 3 days ago in a similar format. if that date is lower (comes before) our reference we do some thinsgs:

    - We set the name of our source and destination directory
    - `if zip -r  "$logArchiveDstZipFile" "$logArchiveSrcDirectory"`: We check to see if the zip command ran without errors
    - `rm -r "$logArchiveSrcDirectory"`: We delete the directory if everything is okay

I'm a little bit tired so I don't know if there's errors. But it seem to work on my side. Is that what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is why:

```
logArchiveSrcDirectory=$LOG_SOURCE"/"$archiveYear"/"$archiveMonth"/"$archiveDay
```

You define your source with `$archiveDay`.  `$archiveDay` is, for today, `13`.

So you are saying to zip to do this:

```
zip -r /tmp/logs/destination/2018_09_132.zip /tmp/logs/source/2018/09/13
```

It will therefore only zip the files in the `.../13` directory.

Now if you want to find all *files* that are older than 3 days, you can use:

```
find <SOURCE DIRECTORY> -type f -mtime +3 -print
```

Careful this will recursively find files in all sub-directories as well.

Comment: Thanks Nic3500, can you explain how to apply given command to my code.